# Java File Sync between Bat and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, synchronization

I have a java main class SendEmail.java that I can run in Eclipse or in a bat file. If I make a change to the code in Eclipse, save, and then run bat file (which runs the java class), an old version of the class runs instead of the new version that has the change. When I run the class in eclipse, the new version runs and I have no problem.

1. Why is it that the bat file doesn't run the updated version?
2. What can I do to the bat file to run the updated version of the class?
3. Is the problem that running the bat file just runs the class (may not compile), while running in eclipse both compiles and runs?

My bat file uses set CLASSPATH for JavaMail's external jars, changes the directory to the location of the package mypack, and then calls this:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true mypack.SendEmail
```

EDIT (info  David Conrad requested):
The .bat file is run from my computer's C drive

```
C:\Users\myusername\myfolder\runSendEmail.bat
```

In runSendEmail.bat, I change the directory to a shared Network Z drive and run the java class

```
Z:
cd Z:\PATH\JAVA_CODE\EMAIL\bin
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true mypack.SendEmail
```

So the .class file is located in the shared Network Z drive at

```
Z:\PATH\JAVA_CODE\EMAIL\bin\mypack
```

The jar files are also in the C drive.

---

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How are you building it? Where does the .class file get generated? Where does the .bat file look for it? (I.e., what directory is the .bat file run from?)

Comment: I edited the question to answer your questions. Hope that is clarified now.

Comment: And is that place on the Z: drive where your Eclipse project is, so that when Eclipse compiles it, it puts the .class file into that `...\EMAIL\bin\mypack` directory? Or did you copy the .class file there manually at some point?

Answer (score 0):

If you have build automatically option enabled in Eclipse, that would compile your code on each save and the updated class file will be available to the bat file too. If that option is not enabled, the project is built only when you ask for it (or when you run), which seems to be the case for you

Comment: I think the place Eclipse compiles it to must be different from where the .bat file is looking for it on the Z: drive.

Comment: Thank you so much Sasikanth! I did Project > Build Automatically and the bat file runs the updated version now! Problem fixed. @DavidConrad yes I checked the project in eclipse and it is in the EMAIL\bin\mypack directory, so the bat file and eclipse point to the same class at the same location. Thank you though!